# OLE DB Command Param order (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis

What exactly determines the order of the Parameters in a OLE DB Command (SSIS). For example, I have a table looks as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimAppointmentFlags] (
  [RowIdentifier] bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  [AppointmentID] bigint,
  [Flag] varchar(255)
)
GO
```

and the statement I am running in the command in SSIS is:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[DimAppointmentFlags]
SET [AppointmentID] = ?,
[Flag] = ?
WHERE [RowIdentifier] = ?
```

My first assumption was that they where in field order i.e.

RowIdentifier is Param_0
AppointmentID is Param_1
Flag is Param_2

I can see that this is not the case though. Can some elaborate on this as I find the official documentation to be not that helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It's in ordinal order in the query. The order of the columns in the table is irrelevant. Truthfully, that would be an *awful* and confusing design choice. Imagine if you had a `SELECT` with 2+ tables referenced with parameters again each; you'd have no idea which is "first". >_<

Comment: Are you actually using SSIS though, or just OLE-DB? How are you using OLE-DB?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. I am using an SSIS package to perform INSERT, UPDATES and DELETES. i.e., Sorting a flat file and DB Source > Merge Join > Conditional Split Transformation and then an OLE DB Command for the updates (inserts are a OLE DB Destination, deletes are also a OLE DB Command).

Comment: AppointmentId = 0, Flag = 1, RowIdentifier = 2. They're in the order they appear in the script.

Answer (score 1):

OLE DB Connection managers and ODBC Connection managers use an ordinal based token replacement system. The token is `?`. The difference is OLE DB uses a zero based counting system whereas ODBC uses a one based.

In your example

```
SET [AppointmentID] = ?,
[Flag] = ?
WHERE [RowIdentifier] = ?
```

The first question mark, for AppointmentID, correlates to the `Param_0` (or just `0` in the Execute SQL, OLE DB Source or Lookup component) value.

The second, Flag, will correlate to Param_1, etc.

Let's take a slightly different variation on your query. Instead of just updating where the row identifier is some value, let's also only update it when the Appointment Id is also a given value. This is a situation where the ordinal based system gets silly.

```
SET [AppointmentID] = ?,
[Flag] = ?
WHERE [RowIdentifier] = ?
-- ADDED THIS PART
AND [AppointmentID] = ?
```

The first AppointmentID is ordinal zero. Flat is ordinal one, RowIdentifier is ordinal two and the last ApppointmentID is ordinal three. Even though the "same" value is being used in both places, it's a "dumb" system where it's literally replace every token exactly once.

For completeness, ADO Connection Managers use Named parameters so it would look something like

```
SET [AppointmentID] = @apptid,
[Flag] = @flag
WHERE [RowIdentifier] = @rowident
-- ADDED THIS PART
AND [AppointmentID] = @apptid;
```

Here we can see that we only have 3 parameters to populate as we reuse @apptid.

Finally, in Execute SQL Commands and I think OLE DB Source (definitely not OLE DB Command or a Lookup), you can get the best of both worlds if you find yourself needing to reference a parameter multiple times in a query by declaring SQL variables and populating them from the parameters.

```
DECLARE @apptid int = ?
,   @flag bit = ?
,   @rowident int = ?;

SET [AppointmentID] = @apptid,
[Flag] = @flag
WHERE [RowIdentifier] = @rowident
-- ADDED THIS PART
AND [AppointmentID] = @apptid;
```

Now we have 3 parameters OLE/ODBC can map in exactly once but we can reuse them as needed in the body of our query. And as a bonus, it's easy to copy that into your query tool and test.

Comment: Wow brilliant! Thank you for this extended explanation very helpful.